# Keep iconified JInternalFrames on top always

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I have 5 `JInternalFrames` in one `JDesktopPane`. I have to keep 4 `JInternalFrames` iconified and keep only 1 active. But when I maximize 1 `JinternalFrame`, other iconified `JInternalFrames` goes behind it, so I have to iconify the active `JInternalFrame` and then restore the required one.

Is there a way that I can keep all my Iconified `JInternalFrames` on top always?

Comment: Wouldn't one JTabbedPane with 5 tabs ideally replace your JInternalFrame's?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet.
Thanks for suggesting workaround Guillaume. :-)
But the thing is that I have to implement that exact working of JInternalFrames as its is there in requiremt from my senior.

Answer (score 4):

Use [JDesktopPane.setComponentZOrder(java.awt.Component, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html#setComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29) and ensure that the iconified frames are in a layer which is above the one that is not iconified.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this helps in your case, but if you want to have a specific ordering (e.g. one JInternalFrame should always be in front of others) then simply dont use a JDesktopPane. Simply use the DefaultPane:

Default:

```
setContentPane(new JDesktopPane());  // Will bring the currently activated JInternalFrame to top
add(frame_A);
add(frame_B);
add(frame_C);
```

Always on top:

```
// setContentPane(new JDesktopPane()); // Dont use the DesktopPane
add(frame_A); // Will always be on top
add(frame_B); // Will always be in front of frame c but behind frame a
add(frame_C);
```